# Scroll KeyboardAwareScrollView to end when rendering view

Tags: react-native

I have a `KeyboardAwareScrollView` that I need it to scroll to the end after a certain event. My component also renders a camera view whenever I press a button. It looks something like this:

```
if(usingCamera){
    return(
        <CustomCameraComponent />
    )
} 

return (
    <KeyboardAwareScrollView innerRef={ref => {
        this.scroll = ref
    }}>
        ...stuff
    </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

`usingCamera` is a boolean state variable, and when I press a button it changes so that it shows the camera view on screen. Then I take a picture, and changes the state back to see the original view (the Keyboard scroll view). When I return from the camera view, I try doing `this.scroll.scrollToEnd()` but it seems that `this.scroll` is not yet loaded so it doesn't scroll down. Is there another way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Workaround you can use but its kinda dirty. I created an issue on github but until then you can go into you node_modules to the source of the dependecie. Then go to `src/KeyboardAwareBase.js` and modify the line 129 as following

old:

```
const bottomYOffset = this._keyboardAwareView.contentSize.height - this._keyboardAwareView.layout.height + this._keyboardAwareView.props.contentInset.bottom;
```

new:

```
      const bottomYOffset = this._keyboardAwareView.contentSize.height - this._keyboardAwareView.layout.height;
```

This is how you workaround the undefinded Error.

PS: I'm using version 2.1.0 of react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview